# static variable in singleton design pattern is always null

Tags: php, pdo, static, singleton

i had written a chat module and in this module for lowering pressure on database i used singleton design pattern for getting pdo Object.this is my driver class that uses singletone pattern:

```
class driver {

protected $_servername= "localhost";
protected $_username= "****";
protected $_password= "****";
protected $_dbname= "***";


private static $instance;
private $dbConn;


  // The db connection is established in the private constructor.
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_servername;dbname=$this->_dbname", $this->_username, $this->_password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $this->dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if(!self::$instance)
    {
      self::$instance = new driver();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function getConnection()
  {
    return $this->dbConn;
  }


public function __clone() {
    throw new Exception("Can't clone a singleton");
}

}
```

in chat class in constructor i use this codde to get the instance:

```
$instance = driver::getInstance();
    $conn = $instance->getConnection();
    $this->_conn =$conn;
```

so if i put a code like

```
echo 123;die();
```

inside `getinstance` static method like this:

```
if(!self::$instance)
    {
      self::$instance = new driver();
      echo 1111;die();
    }
```

it always returns 1111. why static$instance variable not being filled or stay being filled with driver object?

Comment: Have you tried `$this->_conn =$conn; var_dump($conn)`?

Comment: Are you trying to use a singleton as if it were persistent across multiple page accesses? Because it feels like you are, and that's not going to work.

Comment: @jbafford yes thats exaclly what i want to do...so what is your suggestion?